# How to load my JavaScript file in my HTML page (bug)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with : `<script scr="myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>`, 
and a javascript file named myJavaScriptFile.js (in the same folder).

My problem : the javascript don't work because the file is not loaded I think. The "sources" tab of google chrome tool for inspect elements show me NOT my .js file.

I have other pages with script which work well so I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: it is not `scr` its `src`. So it will be `<script src="myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>`

Comment: scr scr scr scr scr scr...

Comment: My bad, sry... 30 minutes to solve a typo :s

Answer (score 5):

It's a misspelling, it should be `src`, not `scr`:

```
<script src="myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>
        ^^^
```

Comment: OMG lol thanks you !!! I'm a little dyslexic at morning I think ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just a typo in your code:
`<script src="myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>`